# What are PIP alternative in arachne-pnr?

Tags: fpga, yosys, ice40

While going through the `router.cc` the file of `arcahne-pnr`, I am unable to understand, how are the programmable interconnect pins PIPs routed? Does it seem PLL is representing the PIPs in the code? Could somebody help to make me clear, what corresponds to PIP in `arachne-pnr`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called switches in the chip database, although I think the router expands this to its own structure.

Certainly nothing to do with PLL (phased locked loops) which are a clocking primitive.